# How do I run a URL when a Google Doc is opened?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs, urlfetch

A simple question I hope. I am trying to establish how I can run a URL in the background whenever a my google document (doc) is opened. This URL will notify me when someone has been into the document.

I was trying to work it our via APPs Script. But am a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

I tried using the onOpen(e) function but I don't think it links to external URLs

Answer (score 0):

Try [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)) in your `onOpen(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). If your needs are more complex, use an "on open" [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).